# no match for 'operator+' in sort in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I have defined a class

```
class Rent
{
    public:    
    int s_time, duration, price, e_time;
    Rent(int s, int d, int p)
    {
        s_time = s;
        duration = d;
        price = p;
        e_time = s + d;
    }
    bool operator<(Rent const &r1)
    {
        return e_time < r1.e_time;
    }
};
```

Wished to sort it on basis of `e_time`, so I have defined `<` over `Rent`, however, I keep getting error

```
rent.cpp:38:12: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<Rent>’ and ‘int’)

     sort(R, R+n);
              ^
```

when I tried `sort(R, R+n);`. `R` is a vector of type `Rent` and `n` is integer(size of the vector).

Besides the above, I tried these two ways but still failed!

```
sort(R, R + sizeof(R)/sizeof(R[0]));
sort(R.begin(), R.end());
```

I googled and got some solutions with lambdas but again the second parameter to sort() is of type int + custom_datatype.

Any help would be great.

Comment: FYI, you should be using an [initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) instead of performing copy assignment in the body of the constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sort(R, R+n);
sort(R, R + sizeof(R)/sizeof(R[0]));
```

will not work if `R` is of type `std::vector<Rent>`. There are two problems with those lines:

1. `operator+()` is not defined for `std::vector`.
2. The compiler expects the `operator<()` function to be a `const` member function.

You can fix the `operator<()` function by making it a `const` member function.

```
bool operator<(Rent const &r1) const
                           //  ^^^^^
{
    return e_time < r1.e_time;
}
```

That still does not resolve the first problem.

However you should be able to use:

```
sort(R.begin(), R.end());
```

after that.

In theory, you shouldn't have to make the `operator<()` function a non-`const` member function. Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort. See the description of the `comp` argument. It says:

> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
> ```
>
> The signature does not need to have `const &`, but the function object must not modify the objects passed to it.

However, not all compilers adhere to that. They expect the signature of the function to be such that they can work with `const` objects.

Comment: How does making it a constant member function result in the code working in this case? I have many times overloaded the < operator without declaring a const member function. What necessitated the use of const here? Just curious as this is the first time I have come across this.

Comment: Thanks, making it `const` worked BTW. But can you tell the logic behind that?

Comment: Why do you bring up the `comp` argument of `std::sort`? That overload is not being used here, right?

Comment: @JamesAdkison, it is not an explicitly specified `comp` but the default one -- `operaor<()` function -- is expected to follow the same semantics, which is that it needs to work with `const` objects.

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/JVZu4x) works for me even without having a `const` member function for `operator<`. To be clear, I think it should be a const member function since it does not modify class state I'm just trying to understand why it wasn't working for OP.

Comment: @JamesAdkison, I am happy to see that. The standard does not mandate a `const` member function. Some compilers are not up to snuff yet. Making a the `operator<()` function a `const` member function is a work around.

Comment: @JamesAdkison , It doesn't work for me on 4.3.2 and 4.9.2 [code](https://ideone.com/hzg6K9), uncomment `const` and everything goes all right

Answer (score 2):

According to error, `R` is a `std::vector<Rent>` but following code:

```
sort(R, R+n);
```

would work only for C style array. If you want generic code that works for both C array and `std::vector` write it as:

```
std::sort( std::begin(R), std::end(R) );
```